# JUnit 5 test suite failing to find any tests

Tags: java, junit, teamcity, junit5, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to upgrade our JUnit 4 test suites to JUnit 5 test suites which is working fine locally in Intellij however when the change is then run on our TeamCity server (2017.2.3) then it is reporting no tests are found:

Build log excerpt:

```
[12:10:18][java] Runtime classpath: [file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/src/server/out/production/Thor/, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/src/server/out/test/Thor/, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/ant.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/antlr-3.4.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/aopalliance.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/cloning-1.7.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-cli.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-collections.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-exec.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-io.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-lang.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-net-3.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-pool-1.5.5.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/datecalc-common-1.2.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/datecalc-joda-1.2.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/dom4j.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/dsn.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/eventbus-1.4.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/google-jtype-0.1.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/google-translate-0.82.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/h2-1.2.137.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/HikariCP-2.4.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/hsqldb.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/imap.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jaxen-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jcommon-1.0.16.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jersey-bundle-1.19.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jersey-spring-1.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jetty-all-9.2.9.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jgrapht.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/joda-time-2.4.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jquery-selectors-0.1.6.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jsoup-1.8.2.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jta-1.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jtds-1.2.5.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-4.13.2.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/mail.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/mailapi.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/NationalGridMarketData.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/netty-3.1.1.GA.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/objenesis-1.2.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/opencsv-2.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/pop3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/rjm-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/simple-xml-2.7.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/smtp.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/javax.mail.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-ldap-1.3.0.RELEASE-all.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-acl-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-cas-client-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-config-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-ldap-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-openid-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-taglibs-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-security-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/sqljdbc4.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/stax-1.2.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/svnkit.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/svntask.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/twilio-7.37.4.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-auth-roles-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-bootstrap-core-0.9.16.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-bootstrap-extensions-0.9.16.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-cdi-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-core-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-datetime-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-devutils-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-extensions-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-guice-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-ioc-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-jmx-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-native-websocket-core-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-native-websocket-jetty9-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-objectsizeof-agent-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-request-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-spring-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-util-6.19.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicket-webjars-0.4.5.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/wicketforge-annotations-1.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/zip4j.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/zxing-core-3.2.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/zxing-javase-3.2.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/poi-3.14-20160307.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/xbean.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jaxb2-rich-contract-plugin-1.17.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jzlib-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/sshj-0.20.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/eddsa-0.1.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/annotations.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/okhttp-3.8.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/okio-1.13.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/itext.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/httpclient-4.5.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/httpclient-cache-4.5.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/httpcore-4.4.6.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/httpmime-4.5.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/aws-java-sdk-1.11.225.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jsr305-2.0.2.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/gson-2.8.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/bootstrap-3.3.6.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/webjars-jquery-1.11.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/webjars-jquery-ui-1.11.4.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-aop-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-aspects-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-context-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-context-indexer-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/guava-retrying-2.0.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/okhttp-2.7.5.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/testng-6.9.6.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/logback-s3-rolling-policy-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-context-support-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-expression-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-instrument-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-jcl-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-jms-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-messaging-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-orm-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-oxm-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-test-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-tx-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-webflux-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-webmvc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/spring-websocket-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/classmate-1.3.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/opentest4j-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-jupiter-api-5.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-jupiter-params-5.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-platform-commons-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-platform-engine-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-platform-launcher-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-platform-runner-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-platform-suite-api-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-platform-suite-commons-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-platform-suite-engine-1.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/mockito-core-2.17.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/byte-buddy-1.8.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/objenesis-2.6.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/assertj-core-3.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/logback-jackson-0.1.5.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/logback-json-classic-0.1.5.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/logback-json-core-0.1.5.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/dnsjava-2.1.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jackson-datatype-joda-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/mockito-junit-jupiter-2.17.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/cucumber-core-4.4.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/cucumber-expressions-7.0.2.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/cucumber-java-4.4.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/cucumber-java8-4.4.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/cucumber-junit-4.4.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/cucumber-spring-4.4.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/datatable-1.1.14.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/datatable-dependencies-1.1.14.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/tag-expressions-1.1.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/typetools-0.5.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/gherkin-5.1.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/stripe-java-10.14.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-io-1.4.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/httpclient-win-4.5.3.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jersey-client-1.19.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jersey-core-1.19.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jersey-json-1.19.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/jersey-multipart-1.19.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/junit-vintage-engine-5.9.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/java-jwt-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/commons-codec-1.11.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/guava-20.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/gocardless-pro-4.5.0.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/bcpg-jdk15on-168.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/bcpkix-jdk15on-168.jar, file:/C:/BuildAgent/work/3f345272db46718f/lib/jar/bcprov-jdk15on-168.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar]
[12:10:18][java] Found classes: []
```

Test suite being run:

```
package junit.suite;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;

@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName( "Full Suite" )
@SelectClasses( { Suite1.class, Suite2.class, Suite3.class, Suite4.class } )
public class FullSuite
{
}
```

Reverting back to the previous test suite is finding the tests as expected:

```
package junit.suite;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith( Suite.class )
@SuiteDisplayName( "Full Suite" )
@Suite.SuiteClasses( { Suite1.class, Suite2.class, Suite3.class, Suite4.class } )
public class FullSuite
{
}
```

I assume the test runner in TeamCity isn't parsing the suite correctly but I'm unsure how to debug that as no issues are being reported in the build log

Edited (Added extra information about TeamCity build step):

TeamCity build step:
[image: TeamCity build step]

Intellij IDEA project used in build step:
[image: Intellij IDEA project used in build step]

Comment: Suites in JUnit 5 require the suite engine. Can you show your pom or Gradle file?

Comment: This is legacy setup that uses ant and ivy instead of pom and gradle.

All of the jars I expected to need are in the classpath:
junit-jupiter-api-5.9.1.jar
junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.1.jar
junit-jupiter-params-5.9.1.jar
junit-platform-commons-1.9.1.jar
junit-platform-engine-1.9.1.jar
junit-platform-launcher-1.9.1.jar
junit-platform-runner-1.9.1.jar
junit-platform-suite-api-1.9.1.jar
junit-platform-suite-commons-1.9.1.jar
junit-platform-suite-engine-1.9.1.jar

Comment: Don’t know about ant, but the ant script must probably be adapted to use the engines of your choice. Maybe you should add it to the question.

Comment: The ant script is used in an earlier build step which is also used locally where this project works as expected so the ant script can't be the issue, the actual test suite execution is triggered via an Intellij IDEA project so I've added that information to the question